# Как изменять данные в ObservableCollection используя telerik radGrid?

Tags: asp.net, c#

Здравствуйте!

С помощью Telerik реализую UI. Нужно сделать radGrid, у нее указываю источник данных `RadGrid1.DataSource = TubesLoad;`
Где TubesLoad - ObservableCollection<T> из моей dll.
С отображением все хорошо, но:
Необходимо, чтобы изменения, вносимые пользователем в radGrid из браузера влияли и на коллекцию.

Я знаю, что нужно для этого обрабатывать события RadGrid1_ItemUpdated, RadGrid1_ItemCreated  , или другое специфичное для действия, но у меня так и не получилось написать код, который бы позволял обновлять коллекцию.

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
var context=myContext; //экземпляр контекста
RadGrid1.ItemSource=myContext.Set<T>.Local; //биндим ObservableCollection<T> к соурсу грида
myContext.Set<T>.Load(); //загружаем записи из БД в ObservableCollection
```

теперь при добавлении записей в грид, MyContext.Set<T>.Local будет тоже обновляться
Для сохранения записей в БД необходимо вызвать myContext.SaveChanges();
если же будете добавлять запси програмно, не забудьте обновить грид RadGrid1.Items.Refresh()

Comment: Не очень понятно, как мне использовать этот код. 

var context=myContext;
Надо объявлять вне всех обработчиков.

RadGrid1.ItemSource=myContext.Set<T>.Local;
у "моего" RadGrid'а нет метода ItemSource, есть только DataSource и e  RadGrid1.Items нет Refresh, может речь идет о другом фреймаорке?
Я использую Telerik for ASP.NET AJAX

Comment: Извините, сразу не увидел, это для Telerik for WPF